# how to associate not registered user with some open id?

Tags: support, reputation, openid, user-accounts

i posted some questions and answers to stackoverflow.com;

i got some reputation on that. i was not registered and some how i cleared my browser data and loose my user data. now i want to use that unregisterd user of stackoverflow.com with some openid so i can get my reputation back.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you are no longer logged in as the guest account? Not a problem. Create an account (like you have here on "meta"), and let me know a: the old account name / e-mail / **something**, and b: your new account (ditto). I can merge them for you (assuming that I can reasonably prove that the two accounts are really the same).